# Asking user for paths to other software in Python scripts: best practices?

Tags: python, config, freecad

I'm developing a Python package for automating an existing piece of software. This software (FreeCAD) comes with a bunch of Python modules and is installed separately by the user.

My package has to know where FreeCAD is installed before it is imported:

`mymodule.py`

```py
if user_has_not_told_me_where_freecad_is:
  sys.path.append('/path/to/default/freecad/bin')
else:
  use_user_supplied_path

import FreeCAD
```

I want my users to be able to do in, say, a Jupyter Notebook, or a standalone script:

`user_script.ipynb`

```py
# this is where the user will tell me where freecad is
set_freecad_path('/path/to/freecad/bin')

import mymodule
# ... do other stuff
```

### Things I tried

I don't think I can do

`user_script.py`

```py
import mymodule
mymodule.set_freecad_path('/path/to/freecad/bin')
```

as mymodule needs to have `FreeCAD` available to start with in `sys.path`?

I tried a few things but not sure which is the most user friendly / best way to do it?

1. ask the user to sys.path.append() at the top of their script --
   Is this good practice? This makes it hard for my code to tell whether the user has specified the path or whether it should default to finding it in the "usual suspect locations"
2. config.toml / .yaml / .ini --
   This would be nice but if I eventually publish this to pypi and users just install it, how do I deal with software upgrades? The software default is to hardcode the version in the path, and is frequently updated.

Comment: I guess this very much depends on how `mymodule` is structured... Why cant you just add an optional kwarg to set a custom path at the __init__() of your main class and then import the desired modules afterwards?

Comment: `mymodule` is currently a [single file module](https://github.com/da-crivelli/freecad-parametric-fea/blob/main/FreecadParametricFEA/freecadparametricfea.py), very WIP at the moment. You can see the offending bit on lines 9-10.

Isn't importing inside methods normally frowned upon?

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on my comment...

There are several circumstances where imports within functions/classes can't really be avoided (if you look closely you'll find a lot of them even in the most popular packages).

If you need to delay the import until you know the location from which you want to import I think there's not really much you can do about it...

In my opinion, a pattern similar to this is "pythonic" enough and should do the job just fine (maybe also use `pathlib` for os-independent path specifications):

```py
def _register_freecad(p=None):
    if p is not None and p not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(p)

    try:
        import FreeCAD
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError(f"{p} is not a valid path to the FreeCAD installation!")



class FreecadParametricFEA:
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        _register_freecad(path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately this doesn't work, as the imported package remains local to the _register_freecad function and isn't available outside.

To make it available I had to import it via `__import__()`: `global FreeCAD`; `FreeCAD = __import__("FreeCAD", globals(), locals())`. The added bonus of your solution is I can scan for typical folders if the user doesn't provide one.